# Nested for-loop: error variable already defined

Tags: loops, stata, nested-for-loop

I have a nested loop in Stata with four levels of `foreach` statements. With this loop, I am trying to create a new variable named `strata` that ranges from 1 to 40.

```
    foreach x in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 {
         foreach r in 1 2 3 4 5 {
             foreach s in 1 2 {
                 foreach a in 1 2 3 4 {
                    gen strata= `x' if race==`r' & sex==`s' & age==`a'
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I get an error :

> "variable strata already defined"

Even with the error, the loop does assign `strata` = 1, but not the rest of the strata. All other cells are missing/empty.

Example data:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte(age sex race)
1 2 2
1 2 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 2 1
2 2 1
2 2 1
4 2 1
1 2 1
4 2 1
3 2 1
2 2 1
4 2 1
4 2 2
3 2 1
4 1 3
4 2 1
4 2 1
2 1 2
4 2 1
2 2 1
3 2 1
3 2 1
1 2 3
4 2 1
1 2 5
4 2 1
4 2 1
4 2 2
4 2 1
2 2 1
4 1 1
3 2 1
1 2 1
2 2 1
4 2 1
1 2 2
2 2 3
1 1 3
4 2 1
2 2 3
1 2 1
1 1 1
2 2 3
1 2 1
1 1 3
1 2 1
2 2 1
3 2 1
1 2 1
4 2 1
1 2 2
1 2 1
2 2 1
4 2 1
4 2 1
1 2 1
1 2 1
4 2 1
2 2 1
4 2 1
1 2 1
1 1 3
2 2 1
1 1 1
4 1 1
3 2 1
2 2 1
1 2 1
1 1 1
2 2 3
4 2 2
2 2 1
2 2 1
3 2 1
2 2 2
3 2 1
2 1 1
1 1 1
3 2 1
1 2 3
4 2 1
4 2 1
2 2 1
1 2 1
1 1 1
3 2 1
4 2 1
2 2 3
1 2 3
4 2 1
3 2 1
2 2 1
4 2 1
3 2 1
2 1 1
1 2 1
2 2 1
2 2 3
1 1 1
end
label values sex sex
label def sex 1 "male (1)", modify
label def sex 2 "female (2)", modify
label values race race
label def race 1 "non-Hispanic white (1)", modify
label def race 2 "black (2)", modify
label def race 3 "AAPI/other (3)", modify
label def race 5 "Hispanic (5)", modify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generate` is for generating new variables. The second time your code reaches a `generate` statement, the code fails for the reason given.

One answer is that you need to `generate` your variable outside the loops and then `replace` inside.

For other reasons your code can be rewritten in stages.

First, integer sequences can be more easily and efficiently specified with `forvalues`, which can be abbreviated: I tend to write `forval`.

```
gen strata = . 
forval x = 1/40 {
    forval r = 1/5 {
        forval s = 1/2 {
            forval a = 1/4 {
                replace strata = `x' if race==`r' & sex==`s' & age==`a'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second, the code is flawed any way. Everything ends up as 40!

Third, you can do allocations much more directly, say by

```
gen strata = 8 * (race - 1) + 4 * (sex - 1) + age
```

This is a self-contained reproducible demonstration:

```
clear
set obs 5
gen race = _n
expand 2
bysort race : gen sex = _n
expand 4
bysort race sex : gen age = _n
gen strata  = 8 * (race - 1) + 4 * (sex - 1) + age
isid strata
```

Clearly you can and should vary the recipe for a different preferred scheme.